# C# request to plugin

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, reflection

I'm trying implement simple plugin system to my app, but i have problem with communication with my plugin.

I made interface to my plugin:

```
public interface IAlgorithm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// New request in current simulation tick - all logic should be run after request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pTime">Simulation time in [ms] from simulation start</param>
    /// <param name="pObject">Manipulating object</param>
    /// <param name="pWorld">Current world</param>
    void Request(int pTime, PhysicalObject pObject, World pWorld);
}
```

and next I create my plugin to hook keyboard:

```
 public class Main : IAlgorithm
{
    private int m_Direction;
    private readonly GlobalKeyboardHook m_Hook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();

    public Main()
    {
        m_Hook.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Up);
        m_Hook.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Down);
        m_Hook.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Right);
        m_Hook.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Left);
        m_Hook.KeyDown += KeyClicked;
    }

    private void KeyClicked(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Down:
                m_Direction = 180;
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                m_Direction = 0;
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                m_Direction = 90;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                m_Direction = 270;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Request(int pTime, PhysicalObject pObject, World pWorld)
    {
        pObject.Movement.Power = 100;
        pObject.Movement.Direction = m_Direction;
    }
}
```

Next in my main program I try to use my plugin like this:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(myPath).GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "Main");
IAlgorithm myAlgorithm = ((IAlgorithm)Activator.CreateInstance(myAssembly ));
```

and it's working, but if I want make some request to plugin

```
myAlgorithm.Request(pSimulationTime, myPhysicalObject, pWorld);
```

after that I don't have any changes in myPhysicalObject

but if I use MessageBox:

```
myAlgorithm.Request(pSimulationTime, myPhysicalObject, pWorld); 
MessageBox.Show(myPhysicalObject.Movement.Direction)
```

I can see correct value in MB.

I don't know what is incorrect in my logic and I don't understand why it's working after some pause. Have you some ideas??

Comment: What do you mean by "after that I don't have any changes in myPhysicalObject"? How are you inspecting these values?

Comment: Is `PhysicalObject` a class or a struct? How about `Movement`? They should be classes, not structs.

Comment: Did you try plugin framework such as MEF?

Comment: Are you checking pObject.Movement.Power too, without MB ?

Comment: I use Power and Direction to move my object and I render that so if I press any key I can't see any changes. I try write my result on Console 
      `Debug.WriteLine($"Obj: {myPhysicalObject.Name}, Direction:      {myLastDirection} => {myPhysicalObject.Movement.Direction}, Power: {myLastPower} => {myPhysicalObject.Movement.Power}");`

But result is always 0 (if I put MB before it's still works). PhysicalObject and Movement are classes.

Comment: I didn't try MEFa, that I need is to simple to use another frameworks, i should understand why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

I expect that it should give you `0` if you have not pressed any key.

Since you have hooked the direction keys, put a log/console.writeline statement in `void KeyClicked(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` to find out the magic.

Comment: I add write to debug console and it works only after MB too (event is fire after show MB). I think than can be problem with main loop (it's simulation) so in every step all the time someting is computing so maybe events can't fire??

Comment: @Kisiel665, with this behavior I suspect that the global key board hook is not working properly. It appears that the MB brings the application in focus & then the key board hooks come into picture.

Comment: To check that i create timer in my plugin and i write to console every 1s (timer tick is event too) and my timer works after simulation end or fire tick after MB (if i use them). Problem is when thread is busy (simulation loop) because no events fire can I do something with that or only way is using another thread to plugin??

Comment: @Kisiel665, so now the issue is seems to be with simulation loop & key board hooks not being called untill MB is displayed. I suggest may be you should open a new question, which is focused around this issue. The current question highlights plugin more but as your experiments reveal, plugin & reflection are not really the problem areas.   May be you can add a simplified code from your experiments too for others to reproduce the problem.